# Gráfica de barras PHP

Tags: php, javascript

El problema es que no me salen los datos de la gráfica hice un arreglo para contar y mostrar los datos. mi duda es que no me salen los ejes de "x , y" ya que gráfico me salen vació no entiendo el porque no sale los datos ya que los mando en los arreglos que hice.

Primero arreglo de estados es donde cuento los cuantos datos son con una consulta SQL
El segundo arreglo es donde hago un arreglo que se llama arrayincremento ahi donde hago una operacion entre 5.

```
<?php
$item = null;
$valor = null;
$estados[0] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos($item,$valor);
$estados[1] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos2($item,$valor);
$estados[2] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos3($item,$valor);
$estados[3] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos4($item,$valor);
$estados[4] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos5($item,$valor);
$estados[5] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos6($item,$valor);
$estados[6] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos7($item,$valor);
$estados[7] = ControladorLicencias::ctrMostrarDatos8($item,$valor);

$arrayestado = array();
$arraylistaestado = array();

$limite = 0;
for($i = 0; $i<=7; $i++){
  if($limite<$estados[$i]){
    $limite=$estados[$i];
  }
}
$incremento = $limite / 5;
$arrayIncremento = array();
$arrayIncremento[0] = 0;
$arrayIncremento[1] = $arrayIncremento[0] + $incremento;
$arrayIncremento[2] = $arrayIncremento[1] + $incremento;
$arrayIncremento[3] = $arrayIncremento[2] + $incremento;
$arrayIncremento[4] = $arrayIncremento[3] + $incremento;
$arrayIncremento[5] = $arrayIncremento[4] + $incremento;

$arrayestado[0] = 'CERRADO';
$arrayestado[1] = 'CANCELADO';
$arrayestado[2] = '100 Review Request';
$arrayestado[3] = '200 Create Order Request';
$arrayestado[4] = '300 Confirm Purchase Order';
$arrayestado[5] = '400 Receive License';
$arrayestado[6] = '500 Install software';
$arrayestado[7] = '600 Reopen Task';
?>
<div class="box box-success">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Tareas</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="chart-responsive">
            <div class="chart" id="bar-chart" style="height: 500px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart',
  resize: true,
  data: [
  <?php
   if($arrayestado != null) {
    foreach($arrayestado as $value){
      echo "{y: '".$value."',a:'".$arrayIncremento[$value]."'},";
    }
    echo "{y: '".$value."',a:'".$arrayIncremento[$value]."'},";
  } else {
    echo "{y: '0',a:'0'},";
  }
  ?>
  ],
  barColors: ['#0af'],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['jj'],
  preUnits: '',
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
</script>
```

[image: Gráfica de barras]

Comment: Cuando la pagina cargue dale Ver codigo fuente en tu navegador y copia la parte del script donde se crea el grafico y ponlo en la pregunta para darnos cuenta de que sucede por detras.